# exception when setting module id

Tags: android, react-native

When Clicking on a component my app crashing without any logs in react-native console. So I thought may be some issue with android.
So I ran this command **adb logcat** and got this error log

```
05-09 17:52:41.083  2488  3263 W GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
05-09 17:52:41.087  2488  7469 I LogUtils: [Places]: ?: Couldn't find platform key file. [CONTEXT service_id=253 ]
05-09 17:52:41.168  2488  2488 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=com.google.android.gms]
05-09 17:52:41.175  2488  2488 I chatty  : uid=10109 com.google.android.gms.persistent identical 1 line
05-09 17:52:41.181  2488  2488 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=com.google.android.gms]
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at com.google.android.chimera.config.ModuleManager.getCurrentModule(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at aewd.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):4)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at aewg.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):9)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at aeso.a(Unknown Source:0)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rpm.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):0)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rlv.c(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):1)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rlt.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):1)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rok.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):6)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rok.c(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):6)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rok.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):10)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rok.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):17)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at rok.g(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):3)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at sdr.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at scr.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):10)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at sci.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):0)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at scl.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):28)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-09 17:52:41.206  2488  2976 E ModuleIdSetter:        at aekz.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
```